# Своя система резервного копирования для проектов

Tags: php, bash, shell, резервное-копирование

У нас много разных веб проектов на поддержке и разработке (около 50 сайтов и интернет магазинов), к некоторым сайтам у нас есть только ftp доступ, к некоторым есть ssh доступ.

Также у нас есть свой сервер, на который мы делаем резервные копии вручную и закидываем на наш сервер.

Хотели бы автоматизировать эту работу. Чтобы с заданной переодичностью происходил бэкап каждого сайта (файловая структура + БД) и эти архивы складывались на наш сервер.

Подскажите пожалуйта как организовать такую работу? Я знаю, что есть много систем готовых, nagios и т.п. Но нас интересует как можно это реализовать средствами php или shell ?

Т.е. какой наш ход действий?

Насколько я понимаю делаем так:

пишем shell скрипт, которые архивирует рекурсивно ту директорию, в которой лежит и архивирует заданную БД (доступы к БД получает по аргументам). После создания архива отправляет их на наш сервер.

Этот скрипт мы закидываем в корень каждого нашего сайта.

Далее пишем еще один скрипт, в котором будем массив наших сайтов, с доступами к БД (для архивации БД). - main.php

И на крон вешаем обработчик, который будет по нужному интервалу дергать скрипт main.php, который в свою очередь будет запускать на всех сайтах shell скрипты, которые будут делать резервные копии.

Вопрос в том, что непонятно, насколько хорош этот метод, или плох? И как быть с тем, что у нас к некоторым хостингам только ftp доступ, мы же не сможем запустить shell скрипты, как быть? что делать?  Может есть примеры у кого?

Comment: По сути вопроса сказать ничего не могу, но на всякий случай предупреждение: если во время копирования копируемые файлы изменятся или в базу что-нибудь запишется, то бэкап может оказаться в не очень консистентном состоянии (а в худшем случае вообще сломанным), и при написании своих бэкап-скриптов стоит не забывать возможность подобного проишествия (хотя для сайтов с малой посещаемостью это скорее всего не будет проблемой)

Comment: Bakula? Почитайте, что оно может. Возможно подойдёт.